# Kotlin / Native c interop with reduced visibility

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

Is it possible to generate c stabs with `internal` visibility?

When using c interop with Kotlin/Native the generated stabs for c functions and structures have `public` visibility. As far as I understand, that means that if someone would use this Kotlin code as a library, the generated stabs will be visible in the target project as well. That fact makes it difficult to create a Kotlin wrapper over the c library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but this behavior is not supported for now.
 
First of all, as cinterop tool produce bindings as a `.klib` file, it is associated with the separate module. So, it won't help if you somehow will mark them as `internal`. 
The `.klib` with the bindings is just another source set of the project.
Then, it should be available to connect it with different [kinds of dependencies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#adding-dependencies). Now because of some language limitations, one cannot use the `implementation` dependency kind to connect Kotlin/Native libraries, only `api` one. But it probably will become available someday.
For now, the best option I can recommend is to name the package as internal or something, to let the consumer know about its practical nature.